# How to make a gradient button in the footer of UICollectionView in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uibutton

I have encountered a problem. I am making an app where I need to make a button that has gradient color on it inside the footer of *UICollectionView*, and the problem is I can not make it via storyboard, so I have to make it programmatically within the footer of *UICollectionView*. But I don't know how to make it.

The thing is I have tried to make it, I have accomplished to make the basic structure of *UIButton* inside *UICollectionView*'s Footer.

```
case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter:

    let footer = outerMainCollectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "Footer", for: indexPath) as! headerReusableView

    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: collectionView.frame.width - 50, height: 40))

    if isGuest {
        button.backgroundColor = .red
    } else {
        button.backgroundColor = .black
    }

    button.setTitle("ALL", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(COLORWHITE, for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(footerButton), for: .touchUpInside)

    footer.addSubview(button)

    footer.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

    return footer
```

I want to make it gradient between light Orange and dark Orange, use any hex values for instance, and I want to make it center height of 40, and margins from all sides - top, bottom, left, right.

Comment: Where is this piece of code placed? Show us `headerReusableView` class

Comment: headerReusableView has nothing to do with my question so i haven't write it down here. i have already got the answer to my question. thank you for your down voting by the way. :-)

Comment: I asked because it looks like you're adding a button every time you dequeue a footer and it's very bad; and btw I didn't downvote -.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collection view itself provides option to add footer using Xib and storyboard but still if you want to add constraints programatically, you can do using below function

```
func addSubviewInSuperview(subview : UIView , andSuperview superview : UIView) {

    subview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

    let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: subview,
                                               attribute: .leading,
                                               relatedBy: .equal,
                                               toItem: superview,
                                               attribute: .leading,
                                               multiplier: 1.0,
                                               constant: 0)

    let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: subview,
                                                attribute: .trailing,
                                                relatedBy: .equal,
                                                toItem: superview,
                                                attribute: .trailing,
                                                multiplier: 1.0,
                                                constant: 0)

    let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: subview,
                                           attribute: .top,
                                           relatedBy: .equal,
                                           toItem: superview,
                                           attribute: .top,
                                           multiplier: 1.0,
                                           constant: 0)

    let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: subview,
                                              attribute: .bottom,
                                              relatedBy: .equal,
                                              toItem: superview,
                                              attribute: .bottom,
                                              multiplier: 1.0,
                                              constant: 0.0)

    superview.addSubview(subview)
    superview.addConstraints([leadingConstraint,trailingConstraint,topConstraint,bottomConstraint])
}
```

To set Gradient to button background:-

```
func setGradient() {
    let color1 =  UIColor.red.cgColor
    let color2 = UIColor.blue.cgColor

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = [color1, color2]
    gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
    gradientLayer.frame = self.view.bounds

    self.btn.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at:0)
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help. i make amendments to your code according to my ease and it is working perfectly fine now. Kudos.

Answer (score 0):

I have extension that will help you add gradient color in `UIButton` and `UIView`.

**Extension**

```
extension UIView {
    func applyGradient(colours: [UIColor]) -> Void {
        self.applyGradient(colours, locations: nil)
    }

    func applyGradient(colours: [UIColor], locations: [NSNumber]?) -> Void {
        let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame = self.bounds
        gradient.colors = colours.map { $0.CGColor }
        gradient.locations = locations
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 0)
    }
}
```

You can use `extension` like below. Make sure to declare button property global in `ViewController` like below example.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var yourButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.yourButton.applyGradient([UIColor.yellowColor(), UIColor.blueColor()])
    }
}
```

Comment: i appreciate your help, but the main issue is the button itself, how do i make it center and put margins from all sides programmatically, i usually make designs on storyboard, but for this purpose, i need programmatic approach. Thank you...